# SCP - "not a directory" - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

On my remote server I have a file named .bash_profile, that file has nothing inside.
I wish to copy a local copy (with something inside) to the remote destination. (overwrite)

So I do:

```
scp ~/path/bla/ble/.bash_profile username@host.com:/home/bleble/.bash_profile
```

I get:

> scp: /home/bleble/.bash_profile: Not a directory

I know it's not a directory.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: If you are coming here from google, verify that the target directory actually exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want to copy the file with the same name, you don't need to specify a target name:

```
scp ~/path/bla/ble/.bash_profile username@host.com:/home/bleble/
```

Because a `.bash_profile` exists in the target directory, `scp` thinks you are giving it a directory as a target, attempts to descend into to it and exits since it is not actually a directory.

Comment: A similar command works for me, so this may be implementation dependent?  `scp fred/.bashrc whmcclos@localhost:fred/.bashrc` copied just fine.  Works same on both OSX (BSD) and Ubuntu (also BSD).

Comment: @BillMcCloskey same here but I guess the OP must have a different implementation. It's the only reason for the described behavior I can think of. Perhaps it was just a typo and the OP ran `cp ~/path/bla/ble/.bash_profile username@host.com:/home/bleble/.bash_profile/`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking typo as well, because I'd expect this to work as was tried.  Oh - that was OSX 10.9.1 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I got this error when mixing up the order of the arguments, i.e. I typed

```
scp selnpcgwnx1001:~ file1 file2
```

instead of the correct

```
scp file1 file2 selnpcgwnx1001:~
```

For some reason I thought that the fact that you can provide multiple files as arguments meant that those arguments have to be placed last. Wrong, you can have multiple files as arguments and then have the target folder as the last argument.